# Authentication Redirection and Security done right?

Tags: laravel-5.1

I am building an Application where alongside general public pages there will be a login page and 3 Dashboard Versions for each 3 role levels.

Table

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->string('firstname');
        $table->string('surname');
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->string('role');
        $table->rememberToken();

        $table->datetime('created_at');
        $table->datetime('updated_at');
    });
```

With that i have another table Roles:

```
Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('role_type');

    });
```

Relationship

```
Users::hasOne('roles');
Roles::hasMany('users');
```

Essentially on login function i want to check the users role_type and then redirect them based on the role.

I would like to know if this table structure and idea is correctly thought out. 
Additionally when a user accesses a specific route i will have the route either display login if no user or 404/503 if user is logged in But does not match a specific role_type.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your users table instead of the **role** column you have, it should be these two lines:

```
$table->integer('role_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
$table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('set null');
```

The downside to this is it allows a null value for the 'role_id' column on users.  The reason it needs this is to deal with what would happen if a Role that is assigned to a user is deleted.

But a better solution would be to use a many-to-many relationship, I personally would suggest using [Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust), since it has what you want built in, plus more options that you might want later.

Comment: Yes I was just reading about entrust and have decided it would be most beneficial for my app. Thanks for you help!

Comment: I have had error after error setting entrust up such a headache